# apply style to genereted html code (multiple divs with no class)

Tags: html, css

html code here 
how apply style to last div in the code
tried but did not work

```
.block-21 div div {}

<div id="block-21" class="utilities clearfix">
<div >
<div style="width: 100%;">
```

Comment: You can give specific class for that div.and you have to use #block-21 div div {} instead of .block-21 div div {}.because it is id.

Comment: Have you closed those `<div>` tags anywhere?

Comment: You should close your `div`s with a `</div>`.

Comment: it is genereted code do i cant change this

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="block-21" class="utilities clearfix">
```

u have ID block-21 not class so use this #block-21 not .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#block-21 div:last-child { }
```

Use the `last-child` pseudo selector.

Or use the `nth-child` selector:

```
#block-21 div:nth-child(2) { }
```

Read more about some [CSS selectors](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/).

Answer (score 0):

Writing  `.block-21` will assign the style to anything with `class="block-21"` but you have `id="block-21"`  Try changing this line to

```
#block-21 div:last-child {
```